# how to train large datasets with Stanford NER CFR

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, stanford-nlp

I'm using [Stanford's NER CRF](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml), and want to train a large datasets, let's say 100k news articles. How do I train the data, how long would it take? I'm new in the machine learning field, and would like to get some direction.

Question 1: 
What do all those variables mean? which ones especially should I be paying attention to?

`numClasses: 8 
numDocuments: 100
numDatums: 48721
numFeatures: 168489
Time to convert docs to data/labels: 1.0 seconds
numWeights: 4317368
QNMinimizer called on double function of 4317368 variables, using M = 25.`

Question 2: Should I run the training on one machine, or distributed systems like Hadoop?

Question 3: The computation appears to be CPU and Memory intensive, how do I overcome these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

- Could you provide more details on your training data.  Usually you train an NER system on human tagged data, such as the 2003 CoNLL dataset.  How much human tagged data do you have?
- The FAQ for the NER system has some advice on reducing memory:

  http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#d
- At this time there is not an option to run the NER training on more than one machine.
- I'm not positive about this, but I think by default the CRFClassifier will use multi-threading when evaluating gradients...if it isn't using multi-threading adding the following to your properties should cause it to start using multi-threading with the number of threads specified:

  ```
  multiThreadGrad=4
  ```